# Rotativa doesn't recognize justify

Tags: css, rotativa

This is the css I used

```
>  p {
>         text-align: justify;
>         text-justify: inter-word;
>     }
```

Comment: Share your proper code.

Comment: @SunilRajput that's all I can share. I don't have any special code added.

Comment: Can u please use text-align: justify !important; for override other Css..

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue my adding this in my css.

```
body {
    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}
```

Comment: This also works if the text is overlapping another

Answer (score 0):

Your css looks good. There might be some other css that is overriding text-align property

Comment: I tried removing all css, but still no luck.
But in browser it looks good.